# How would I get my DFA to loop

Tags: c++

I'm making a program that checks to see if a user input string is a valid literal or not.

My question is how would I loop thought the numbers (i.e. 0, ...,9). The user can input as many numbers as the want or none at all.

This what I wave so far looking at case 1:

```
case 0: if(str[i] == '+' || '-'){ // if first char in the array = (null, +, -)
               s=1; // pass test case -> move to next test case
               i++; // move to next char in the string
        }
        else if (str[i] != '+' || '-'){goto a1;} // this case is the null test case -> moves to next test case; string still not a failure
        else // fail test case -> the string is automatically a failure
            done=true; break;

case 1: a1: if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9'){ // if next char in the array = (null, 0, ..., 9)
     //HERE: how to make a loop check for however many numbers user has input.
               s=2;
               i++;
             }
             else if (str[i] != (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')){goto a2;}
             else
                 done=true; break;
```

I'm thinking of using a simple for loop.

Comment: I can guarantee you neither this: `if(str[i] == '+' || '-')` nor this: `else if (str[i] != '+' || '-')` do what you think they do.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, `goto`s, been a while.

Anwyay, you can do:

`std::all_of(str.cbegin(), str.cend(), [](char c){return std::isdigit(c);});`

Comment: Sorry I though it's `is_digit()`, edited. This should compile now.